# Campagnolo Crank Compatibility 11 speed crank to 9 speed chain/deraillieur/shifters

Tags: derailleur, crankset, drivetrain, compatibility, campagnolo

I need to replace my 9 Speed Campagnolo Racing T Crank with a new one which uses the power torque system.

Is a 11 Speed Athena (or 10 speed Centaur) crank compatible with the racing t front dérailleur and the 9 speed Chorus shifters?

http://www.campagnolo.com/WW/en/Components/athena_crankset

**Bike parts**

- Campagnolo Chrous Ergopower 9-Speed
- Campagnolo Chrous Brakes
- Campagnolo raceing t Crank (needs to be replaced)
- Campagnolo raceing t front derailleur
- Campagnolo raceing t rear derailleur
- Campagnolo Chorus Cassette 9-Speed
- Campagnolo C9 Chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Shimano 10 speed cranks with 9spd chain, derailluers and gears.

Without actually having tried it with the Campy components you list, I see no reason why it shouldn't work. The only difference between 9spd and 11 spd chain is the exterior width of the chain. The interior dimensions are identical (i.e. 3/32 of an inch wide, 1/2 inch long).

The one issue you may run into is that the front chainrings may be slightly closer together
than a 9 speed crank. When you are using gear combos that involve the cross chaining on the small chainring, the extra width of 9 speed chain may catch on the larger chainring.

The shifting may not be as precise and fast as an all 11 speed setup, but of all the parts of the drivetrain the front cranks are the least "speed specific" and the easiest to interchange.

Answer (score 1):

The Centaur 10s crank will give you the closest-to-original performance but the problem areas are all around the width and overall design of the chain.

Whilst the post fromFred above is true insofar as it states that the external dimension of the chain is different, it neglects to say that because of that width difference, in addition to a difference in chain construction, the way that the front derailleur and the chain interact is different.

Occasionally the chain will "ride" or "float" when going from a big chainring to a smaller one, without cleanly engaging the teeth of the chainring. Going "up", there is a problem in that the ramps on the chainrings are designed to engage the outer cage plate of the chain to help it "lift" - the 9s chain does not have flush rivets, they protrude slightly, so the upshift ramps don't work anything like as well - you can mitigate this by also changing the chain to a 10s Ultra Narrow chain and adjusting the FD with great care.

It is not a combination that we would advise, however.

As the main Campagnolo factory-appointed Warranty and Service Centre for the UK, we can assure you that the above answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've just replaced my Campag 9 speed Mirage 53/39 crankset with a Campag 11 speed Over Torque Carbon crankset with EXCELLENT results. Shifts even more smoothly than the original. Had to set the limiting screws off of the front derailleur to prevent the chain from being thrown of onto the crank arms during quick shifts. Using a Record C9 chain and a Campag 13-28 9 speed cassette and original Mirage front derailleur and shifters

Comment: To clarify, your answer is "yes the original front derailleur and shifter worked on a new power torque crank for me."     ?

Answer (score 0):

I have ridden several thousand kms on full 9-speed Campagnolo Veloce setup and more than 10k with otherwise same components but 10-speed Chorus crankset. In my experience the mismatched set works far better than full Veloce 9 and does not have the problems described by Graeme. That being said, I'd pick the 10 speed one since difference is smaller.

My guess is that chain and chainring design does not play a large part in this, but the fact that Veloce chainrings are pressed sheet metal and Chorus ones machined from thicker plate.